# Upgrade to Swift 4. iOS Charts won't build

Tags: ios, swift, charts, swift4, ios-charts

I'm using the Charts library from Github.  The documentation indicates the Pod is updated to support XCode 9 and Swift 4 yet I'm getting errors.

I removed the pod by opening the podfile and removing that line.  I then enter Pod Install into terminal, to remove it.  I then reinstalled to make sure I have the most up to date branch.

The instruction is:

> Add pod 'Charts' to your Podfile.

My error message is:

> Cannot subsript a value of type [String: AnyObject] with an index of
>   type NSAttributedStringKey

The error occurs on the second and third line of this function:

```
var attrs = [String : AnyObject]()

attrs[NSFontAttributeName] = description.font
attrs[NSForegroundColorAttributeName] = description.textColor

ChartUtils.drawText(
    context: context,
    text: descriptionText,
    point: position!,
    align: description.textAlign,
    attributes: attrs
)
```

Comment: What version are you using? It seems you haven't updated to 3.0.3

Comment: It's not clear to me what version I'm using as the instructions don't mention one in the Pod Install.  I gather I should be installing the pod like so:
pod 'Charts', ~> 3.03'
In my Podfile. Is this correct?  Thanks

Comment: Try it with `'Charts', '3.0.3'`, it's possible your local pods definitions are not updated, therefore the last version would not be used when installing.

Comment: Thank I'll try right now.

Comment: I'm sorry.  I'm getting an odd message on Pod Install:
[!] Unable to satisfy the following requirements:

- `Charts (= 3.0.3)` required by `Podfile`
I deleted Charts by removing line and entering Pod Install.  Then entered the line you suggested and installed again.

Comment: You will probably need `pod repo update` to update the local definitions.

Comment: Yes.  I was just reading up on that.  Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

1. I downloaded the new Swift 4 version and replaced the charts xcodeproj in my project, and it went like cream (Very smooth and easy) no 3.0.3 or pods (what are pods?)
2. The error in your question occurred when I upgraded to Swift 4 with the old Swift 3 charts source code. The error relates to type, and in my case mostly had a fix.

Excellent package well done Daniel